# accessing picker indise layout controllers

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin

Hi there, I am currently trying out the idea of a picker inside a listview.
I have assigned a name to said picker but I don't think I can reference this picker from code behind due to all the layers it has on top. Any suggestions on this?

```
 <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding CUSs}" HasUnevenRows="True"
          Margin="10,20"
          ItemTapped="ListView_ItemTapped"
          BackgroundColor="Silver">

    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ViewCell>
                <StackLayout x:Name="ClientLevel" Padding="20">
                    <Label Text="{Binding .ClientName}"
                           TextColor="#000" FontSize="Small"/>

                    <StackLayout x:Name="UnitLevel" Padding="10"  IsVisible="{Binding IsVisible}">
           here --> <!--<Picker x:Name="SubPicker" Title="{Binding .UnitName}" HorizontalOptions="Start" IsVisible="True"/>-->
                    </StackLayout>

                </StackLayout> 
            </ViewCell>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

Once I am able to reference this son-of-a-picker (sorry.Had to xD) I expect the code to work as intended. The user goes down the list and picks a picker for the list ( in this case there is only one of course)

Comment: you can't access elements inside of a template by name because there will be multiple copies of them in the ListView.  Why do you need to do this?

Comment: hmm makes sense. My vision was to use a list view inside a listview and have it expand on an tapped event. I had been working on that idea but decided to go for this instead ( piker inside a listview). My app will generate different information depending on what the user selects here.

Comment: nested listviews are NOT a good idea

Comment: I am currently porting a windows ce app and I have gone through about 80% of the code and I know a port is doable ( just tedious) however this specific form is (and will be) quite an issue. back then, de devs used a dataset tree and used it's parent-child structure to display the info that way. I haven't been able to figure out a similar approach.

Comment: Just realized I have been focusing too much on having the app "look" the same ( virtually impossible) instead of it "feeling" the same. All I need is to have 3 pickers and just change the content of the 2 latter accordingly! How did I not think about that!